# using pm2 with ansible

Tags: node.js, npm, ansible, pm2

I am trying to start a node program using pm2 via ansible. The problem is that the `pm2 start` command is not idempotent under ansible. It gives error when run again.

This is my ansible play

```
- name: start the application
  become_user: ubuntu
  command: pm2 start app.js -i max
  tags: 
    - app
```

Now if i run this the first time then it runs properly but when i run this again then i get the error telling me that the script is already running.

What would be the correct way to get around this error and handle pm2 properly via ansible.

Comment: why not just use the pm2 as service with startup script?

Comment: @ArbabNazar I want to setup a server completely using ansible i.e. to the point of starting of service. So I need ansible to handle this step also. My main problem is that this play is not idempotent and fails if I run it again.

Comment: I ran the pm2 as service using ansible even in production

Comment: Can you share some play code?

Answer (score 6):

Before starting the script you should delete previous, like this:

```
 - name: delete existing pm2 processes if running
   command: "pm2 delete {{ server_id }}"
   ignore_errors: True
   become: yes
   become_user: rw_user


 - name: start pm2 process
   command: 'pm2 start -x -i 4 --name "{{server_id}}" server.js'
   become: yes
   become_user: rw_user
   environment:
    NODE_ENV: "{{server_env}}"
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But what about those cases where pm2 is already running and I run the ansible job again. In those cases, the start play will fail.
Also if I delete existing processes every time I run my playbook then it will cause disruption in service.

Comment: @shivams but before start new process I'm using `pm2 delete {{ server_id }}` to delete prevoius, I'm using this solution and it works, when I deploy new app version

Comment: Yes, this will work great if you are deploying new app version, but what if I run the play again on existing setup, in that case, I am looking at app restart right.

Comment: @shivams At this point it works without a problem in my app, but there is ofcource command to restart specific process `$ pm2 restart 0          # Restart specific process id`  and if you afreaid about disruption in service you can preprare your app to grecfull restart using instructions from http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/signals-clean-restart/

Comment: If an app is already running then the play will fail with reason. I can put ignore_errors there and print the stderr in debug to check if that is the case.
For deployment i can follow your method easily.

Comment: pm2 has a command startOrReload - http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

Answer (score 3):

I ended up on this page looking for a solution to `start` PM2 multiple times when I rerun my playbook. I also wanted PM2 to reload the server when it was already running and pickup the new code I might have deployed. It turns out that PM2 has such an interface:

```
- name: Start/reload server 
  command: '{{path_to_deployed_pm2}} startOrReload pm2.ecosystem.config.js'
```

The `startOrReload` command requires a so-called "ecosystem" file to be present. See the documentation for more details: [Ecosystem File](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#ecosystem-file).

This is a minimal `pm2.ecosystem.config.js` that is working for me:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    script: 'app.js',
    name: "My app"
  }],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use

`pm2 reload app.js -i max`

It will allow you to reload configuration ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use the "register" module to perform a conditional restart/start.

register the output of following command:

```yaml
shell: pm2 list | grep <app_name> | awk '{print $2}'
register: APP_STATUS
become: yes
```

and the use APP_STATUS.stdout to make a conditional start and restart tasks. This way we don't need a pm2 delete step.