# pm2 unable to register service on port when started with ansible

Tags: node.js, ansible, devops, pm2, cicd

I have the following ansible playbook

```
- name: "update apt package."
  become: yes
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
 
- name: "update packages"
  become: yes
  apt:
    upgrade: yes
    
- name: "Remove dependencies that are no longer required"
  become: yes
  apt:
    autoremove: yes   
   
    
- name: "Install Dependencies"
  become: yes
  apt:
    name: ["nodejs", "npm"]
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes

- name: Install pm2
  become: yes
  npm:
    name: pm2
    global: yes
    production: yes
    state: present

- name: Creates Directory
  become: yes
  file:
    path: ~/backend
    state: directory
    mode: 0755

- name: Copy backend dist files web server
  become: yes
  copy:
    src: ~/project/artifact.tar.gz
    dest: ~/backend/artifact.tar.gz
    
- name: Extract backend files
  become: yes
  shell: |
    cd ~/backend
    tar -vxf artifact.tar.gz
   #pwd
    
- name: Executing node
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  shell: |
    cd ~/backend
    npm install
    npm run build
    pm2 stop default
    pm2 start npm --name "backend" -- run start --port 3030
    pm2 status
    cd ~/backend/dist
    pm2 start main.js --update-env
    pm2 status
```

I have the following issue with the task `Executing node`. So on my remote server, if I run each of the commands manually, after logging onto the remote machine via SSH, as `root` user, pm2 starts the services as expected as I can also confirm from `pm2 status`. I can also verify that the service is bound to port 3030 and listening on it (as expected).
But when I try doing the same using Ansible playbook, PM2 does start the service, but for some reason it does not bind the service to the port 3030 as I can see there is nothing listening on 3030.

Can someone please help?

**Major edit 1**
I also tried breaking up the entire task into smaller ones and run them as individual commands through the command module. But the results are still the same.

Updated `roles` playbook:

```
- name: "update apt package."
  become: yes
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
 
- name: "update packages"
  become: yes
  apt:
    upgrade: yes
    
- name: "Remove dependencies that are no longer required"
  become: yes
  apt:
    autoremove: yes   
   
    
- name: "Install Dependencies"
  become: yes
  apt:
    name: ["nodejs", "npm"]
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
- name: Install pm2
  become: yes
  npm:
    name: pm2
    global: yes
    production: yes
    state: present
- name: Creates Directory
  become: yes
  file:
    path: ~/backend
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
- name: Copy backend dist files web server
  become: yes
  copy:
    src: ~/project/artifact.tar.gz
    dest: ~/backend/artifact.tar.gz
    #dest: /home/ubuntu/backend/artifact.tar.gz
    
- name: Extract backend files
  become: yes
  shell: |
    cd ~/backend
    tar -vxf artifact.tar.gz
    
- name: NPM install
  become: true    
  command: npm install
  args:
    chdir: /root/backend
  register: shell_output
- name: NPM build
  become: true  
  command: npm run build
  args:
    chdir: /root/backend    
  register: shell_output
 
- name: PM2 start backend
  become: true  
  command: pm2 start npm --name "backend" -- run start
  args:
    chdir: /root/backend  
  register: shell_output  
- name: PM2 check backend status in pm2
  become: true
  command: pm2 status
  args:
    chdir: /root/backend  
  register: shell_output  
- name: PM2 start main
  become: true
  command: pm2 start main.js --update-env
  args:
    chdir: /root/backend/dist    
  register: shell_output
- debug: var=shell_output
```

No change in the result even with the above:

[image]

while running the same manually, either individually each command on the bash shell or through a `.sh` script (as below) works just fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/backend
pm2 start npm --name "backend" -- run start
pm2 status
cd dist
pm2 start main.js --update-env
pm2 status
pm2 save
```

[image]

Sometimes, even the manual steps also do not get the port up and listening while the service is still up. But this happens rarely and I am unable to consistently reproduce this issue.

Why is this not working is my primary question. What's am I doing wrong? My assumption is that, conceptually, it should work.

My secondary question is how can I make this work?

Comment: Why don't you use the purposed module for all this? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html; https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/npm_module.html#parameter-ci; ...

Comment: Also, have you red https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152620/using-pm2-with-ansible?

Comment: i went through the links you provided. None of them seem to suggest an answer in the direction of my question. To re-iterate, my primary question is *why* is my approach not working. What is wrong with it? 
My secondary, latent question is: how do I make it work? (the other SO link in your comment is not what I am looking for and the other 2 links from the ansible docs, I am sorry I did not understand where it talked about pm2)

Comment: You are trying to stuff commands in Ansible like if it was a simple shell wrapper. Which is all wrong. Use the purposed modules to achieve all this.